# Call method before SWRevealViewController is shown

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using the SWRevealViewController plugins, it works great and I can navigate fine around the pages. My issue is that when the menu is being shown you can still interact with objects on the view that called the menu. I want to disable buttons from my view whilst the menu is shown. I am assigning the sidebar button using this code.

```
_sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.1f alpha:0.9f];
_sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_sidebarButton.tag=10;
_sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

I cannot work out how to call a function in my own class before the revealToggle action is fired. Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe the library has delegates that fire when the menu is about to be shown and close. You could use those?

Comment: There is a `SWRevealViewControllerDelegate` that you can implement. Check out its methods.

Comment: I have added the delegate and added the methods to my class but they do none of the delegate methods seem to be called at all

Answer (score 0):

In MenuViewController (which is rear viewcontroller) write following:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [self.revealViewController.frontViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

   [self.revealViewController.frontViewController.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

then you can get each subview from this viewcontroller.
for example if frontviewcontroller is `UINavigationController`, you can do like this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;

UIViewController *rootViewController = [navController.viewControllers firstObject];  

NSArray *allViews = [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSArray *)[rootViewController.view subviews]];
```

Comment: this does work, but the problem is that it stops me being able to drag back the view.